# Outlook VBA fails to save changes to MailItem on older items only

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

I have a macro in Outlook VBA that is designed to set the category of the selected email and send a reply email to the sender when a user clicks a button on the "Ribbon".

The below code will properly set the category on any newer emails, but throws "Run-time error '440': Cannot save this item." when run on emails that have been sitting around for a while. I don't know what causes this, as it runs fine for a while and then no longer works.

I tried restarting Outlook, logging in and logging out, and restarting the computer, and none of these seem to trigger the change in behavior, so I believe it is somehow related to the duration that the email has been sitting. This is rather confusing, as I don't see why length of time sitting in the folder should affect the ability to save, but not the ability to access the properties of the MailItem.

A simplified version of the code (without the email-sending part, which works fine) is as follows:

```
Public Sub UpdateCategory
    Dim objItem as Object

    Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()

    'Verify that selected item is an email and an engineering request
    If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" And InStr(LCase(objItem.Subject), "engineering request") > 0 Then
        objItem.Categories = "Test"
        objItem.Save
    End If

    Set objItem = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this is an Exchange mailbox, it is possible that Exchange modified the item on the server side, that change was downloaded to the OST file, but since Outlook Object Model is not aware of the change, when you try to save the (stale) item, you get a conflict error.

Comment: This is an Exchange mailbox. This seems plausible, is there a way around it? How would I make sure that the macro is referencing the latest version of the item?

Comment: There is no much you can do - you can release the item as soon as you are done with it. If you need to open it in the future, reopen it by the (previously saved) entry id using Namespace.GetItemFromID. As a rule of thumb, do not keep Outlook items referenced for any prolonged periods of time (open. modify save, release) and avoid having to save the item multiple times - make all the changes in a single pass,.